# Вывод елемента(изображения) по тегу, имя которого введённый в инпуте

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести правильное изображение после ввода в ***input***, все изображения имеют совпадения с данными из атрибута `data-tag`.

Есть ***6*** изображений. На них изображено то, что прописано в `data-tag`. На странице мы должны вывести нужную картинку вписав значение этого тега.

Например на первой картинке изображена ***игра бейсбол***.

Вывод картинки осуществляется вводом слов ***baseball, sport или people***.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var lista = [elem[0], elem[1], elem[2], elem[3], elem[4], elem[5]]
  var botoonShow = document.getElementById('showButton');
  var botooHide = document.getElementById('hideButton');
  var inputt = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var inp = document.getElementById("tagInput")
  botoonShow.onclick = function() {
    oninput = function() {
      document.getElementById('txtprev1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("tagInput").value;

    };
    oninput();
  };
  botooHide.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('txtprev1').remove();
  };
};
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="gallery">
    <img data-tag="baseball,sport,people" src="images/1.jpeg">
    <img data-tag="bike,people" src="images/2.jpeg">
    <img data-tag="motorbike,sport,people" src="images/3.jpeg">
    <img data-tag="people" src="images/4.jpeg">
    <img data-tag="people,nightlife" src="images/5.jpeg">
    <img data-tag="nightlife" src="images/6.jpeg">
  </div>

  <input id="tagInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter tag here">
  <p id="txtprev1"></p>
  <button id="showButton">Show</button>
  <button id="hideButton">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var botoonShow = document.getElementById('showButton');
  var botooHide = document.getElementById('hideButton');

  botoonShow.onclick = function() {
    hideAll();
    
    var inp = document.getElementById("tagInput");
    inp.value.split(",").forEach(tag => {
      document.querySelectorAll("#gallery img[data-tag*='," + tag + ",']").forEach(
        i => i.classList.remove("hide"));
    });
  };

  botooHide.onclick = hideAll;
  function hideAll() {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#gallery img");
    imgs.forEach(i => i.classList.add("hide"));
  }
  
  hideAll();
};
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img data-tag=",baseball,sport,people," src="images/1.jpeg">
  <img data-tag=",bike,people," src="images/2.jpeg">
  <img data-tag=",motorbike,sport,people," src="images/3.jpeg">
  <img data-tag=",people," src="images/4.jpeg">
  <img data-tag=",people,nightlife," src="images/5.jpeg">
  <img data-tag=",nightlife," src="images/6.jpeg">
</div>

<input id="tagInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter tag here">
<p id="txtprev1"></p>
<button id="showButton">Show</button>
<button id="hideButton">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Igor, привет... А запятые перед каждым первым словом в ***data-tag***, в чем секрет?  Не думаю, что это банальная опечатка...)))

Comment: @Air чтобы можно было сделать вот так: `'," + tag + ",'` и защититься от случая, когда один тэг - часть другого - `bike`/`motorbike`

Comment: @Air хотя, может быть автору надо как раз наоборот. Ну поправит тогда.

Comment: Хмм...))) Я бы не догадался)))

Comment: Нет, всё отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Air Мы это как-то использовали в SQL, когда надо было фильтровать записи по полю, содержащему много значений, которые могли пересекаться